# Get output line by line with git hook

Tags: git, bash, output, hook

I have a `post-receive` hook on the server:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/www/project/sources || exit 1
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master
```

I have a `post-merge` hook on on /project/source:

```
#!/bin/sh

sh /var/git/hooks-scripts/clean /var/www/project/sources
```

All is working fine when I run my `git push`, except that the output of my `/var/git/hooks-scripts/clean` script is send when all is finished and not line-by-line. How can I have a line-by-line output?

EDIT:

As requested, the clean script

```
#!/bin/bash

# define composer cache firectory
export COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR="/tmp/.composer-cache"

no_color="\\033[0;39m"
blue="\\033[1;34m"
yellow="\\033[1;33m"
green="\\033[0;32m"

end_script() {
    echo "\n${yellow}*** Configuration du projet ${blue}BAO${yellow} terminé ***${no_color}\n"

    exit $1
}

check_run() {
        echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && echo " * changes detected in $1" && echo " * running $2" && eval "$2"
}

echo "\n${yellow}*** Configuration du projet ${blue}BAO${yellow} en cours ***${no_color}\n"

cd $1/scripts/cli || end_script 0

php console.php clean cache
php console.php clean thumbnails
php console.php symlink modules

cd $1

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id HEAD@{1} HEAD)"
check_run composer.lock "composer update -q -o"

echo "${green}✔${no_color} done"

end_script 0
```

Comment: What do you mean "is send when all is finished"? You mean you don't see any output until the script is finished doing its work? What does that script do? How does it generate output? (Why are you manually using `sh` *inside* a `sh` script?)

Comment: @EtanReisner yes I don't see anything until the script if finished, sorry for my bad explanation. I don't know for the `sh`, I can remove it if needed. This will fix the problem?

Comment: The script makes several tasks and uses `echo` after each tasks.

Comment: No, the `sh` likely isn't hurting it is just pointless. You could try outputting to standard error instead of standard output but I'm not sure that'll help any.

Comment: It should output line by line, for further investigation show us the "clean script" or replace it with something like `echo A; sleep 5; echo B`

Comment: @jandob The script is added